# Why cant i create a variable?

Tags: c++

I have two class: Clique and Graph,
when i try to create "Clique c" in the Graph class, VS give me two errors:

error C2065: 'Clique' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'c' : undeclared identifier

I tried to solve it for a long time and i'm stuck, pls help me.
this is my code:

Clique: http://pastebin.com/jw3FQv95
Graph: http://pastebin.com/bwLakmY0

thanks.

Comment: Post a minimal, complete example *here*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular inclusion, `Graph.hpp` includes `Clique.hpp` and `Clique.hpp` includes `Graph.hpp`.

Since to allocate a Clique in Graph class you need to know its full definition, you are forced to move the method that requires it in a separate source file (`Graph.cpp`) so that you will have something like

```
/* Clique.hpp */
#include "Graph.hpp"

class Clique { ... }

/* Graph.hpp */
// possibly a forward declaration to Clique here
class Graph {
  ...
  Graph(const std::string &file, const double &th, const bool &debug, const bool &convert, const int &max_clique);
};

/* Graph.cpp */
#include "Clique.hpp"

Graph::Graph(const std::string &file, const double &th, const bool &debug, const bool &convert, const int &max_clique)
{
  ...
}
```